# Insert multiple record from datagridview into my database table useing VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

i want to `insert` records from `datagridview` to  `mysql database table` , 
but i dont know how to insert  `datagridview` to database `table`.
How to do it? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is jus my suggestion if you have you code then can work out more better

```
   Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ''create connection 
        Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection()
        conn.Open()

        Dim comm As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
        comm.Connection = conn

        ''insert data to sql database row by row
        Dim name, ageAs String
        For i As Integer = 0 To Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Count
            name = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).ToString()
            age= Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).ToString()

            comm.CommandText = "insert into mytable(name,age) values('" & name & "','" & age& "')"
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next

        conn.Close()

    End Sub
```

This is just a way to insert it is best it you use stored procedure to insert the value because if you use SQL it might happen SQL Injection. So stored procedure is the best way and save to use.

Comment: how about if i want to insert with multiple row from datagridview ? 
or may be you have any idea to my problem ? 
anyway, thank for your help

Comment: My suggestion is for your to use Stored Procedure. You jus need to create once can be used multiple times within the query.

Comment: Use the newer code. this will help you actually since using the for each loop.

Comment: thank you  so much kumar, 
its very helpfull
i can insert to mysql from datagridview now,

Answer (score 2):

kumar, there is a problem with your code

```
name = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).ToString()

  age= Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).ToString()
```

SHOULD BE

```
name = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString()

  age= Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the line of your code:

```
 For i As Integer = 0 To Me.AddPurchases.Rows.Count
```

with this line:

```
 For i As Integer = 0 To Me.AddPurchases.Rows.Count - 1
```

The above is the solution for the exception of verohwm's message. *

Answer (score 0):

instead of inserting data I was trying to update the record and for me

Me.AddPurchases.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString()

this statement did not solve the purpose this statement will return the row count and column count like { row=0,col=1} next iteration  { row=0,col=1} and so on
but

```
Dim roid As String

    For i As Integer = 0 To Me.edit_role_grid.RowCount - 1
        roid = Me.edit_role_grid.Rows(i).Cells(0).FormattedValue
        MsgBox(roid)
```

this worked fine for me, this is returning the text of the cell and now this value can be used anywhere